# Add PreferenceFragment on FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I use the last SDK to create an app with navigation type **Tabs + Swipe** and I want to put a PreferenceFragment on one of the tabs.

The generated code is like :

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

// Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

Meanwhile, I can't add *PreferenceFragment* on the *SectionsPagerAdapter* because its method *getItem(int position)* returns a Fragment, not a *FragmentActivity*.

I may need some help right here.

Comment: I would love to see an answer to this as I'm having the exact same problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that ViewPager's `getItem(..)` method returns a support Fragment (i.e. `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`) rather than `android.app.Fragment`, which is what PreferenceFragments extend. Basically, a PreferenceFragment uses the non-support version of the APIs and so is incompatible with ViewPagers, and there is no support version of PreferenceFragment available.

Comment: Any idea of a workaround? Just creating a normal Fragment with custom controls?

Comment: Thanks, @Espiandev; your answer led me to the workaround in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade to a v13 pager which supports the android.app.Fragment. I gave a detailed answer on a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16286631/279175).