# Adding PreferenceFragment to FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to add a  `PreferenceFragment` to a `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

My class extends `FragmentActivity`, I have tried `FragmentTransaction`, as shown below as well as trying to add to the container and can't seem to get anything to work. *No* errors are thrown, in fact nothing happens.

**Main Activity:**

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```xml
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**My Options menu selection:**

```java
android.app.FragmentManager fm;
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_settings:
        JJSettings settings = new JJSettings();
        fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fm.beginTransaction();
        // I also tried `replace()` here as well. Same 'nothing happens' result.
        fragTrans.add(settings, "settings");
        fragTrans.commit();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_help:
        menuHelp();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**My settings** `Fragment`**:**

```java
public class JJSettings extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }
}
```

My preference would be to stick with `Fragments` if possible, meaning I'd rather not extend `PreferenceActivity` or take the user to another Activity that calls the `PreferenceFragment`, if at all possible. I'm just hoping I missed something in my research.

---

**Edit**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private int _count = 2;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) { super(fm); }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new JJMainFragment();
        case 1:
            return new JJPendingFragment();
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setCount(int count) { this._count = count; }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { return this._count; }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.c_list).toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.c_pending).toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your SectionsPagerAdapter code?

Comment: @Karakuri Added, Not 100% sure why you wanted to see it, I don't want to add the settings/preference to the `ViewPager`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501424/fragmentpageradapter-exists-only-in-android-support-v4-app-and-not-android-app) led me to the solution of using the v13 support library, which includes a FragmentPagerAdapter that uses bona-fide android.app.Fragments so it can support the PreferenceFragment.

Assuming you use Eclipse and run the new app wizard with the "Scrollable Tabs + Swipe" Navigation (which gives you the v4 pager boilerplate), here are the modifications you need to make to upgrade to v13:

- Delete "android-support-v4.jar" file from your libs folder
- Copy "android-support-v13.jar" from SDK_PATH\extras\android\support\v13; if it's not there, use the SDK manager to install or update "Extras/Android Support Library"

Then, in the Java file:

- Change FragmentPagerAdapter import from v4 to v13
- Change FragmentActivity to a plain Activity
- Change calls to getSupportFragmentManager to getFragmentManager
- Import all necessary classes from android.app instead of android.support.v4
- (Except: you still need to use the v4 ViewPager, but it's compatible)

I've copied the modified source below, verified on latest Jellybean.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.pagerwithpreferencesfragment;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter; // instead of v4.app...
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity { // no longer FragmentActivity

    // these comments are now out-of-date; v13, not v4
    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getFragmentManager()); // instead of getSupportFragmentMangager

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // this is just to show it compiles
            if (position == 0) {
                // you should really make this a public class elsewhere..
                return new PreferenceFragment() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_preferences);
                    }
                };
            }
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                    container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

settings_preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <PreferenceCategory
      android:key="my_category_key"
      android:title="My Title">

       <CheckBoxPreference
         android:key="pref_key"
         android:title="Title"
         android:summary="Summary"
         android:defaultValue="false"
         />

   </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

[image]

Comment: This is very interesting, I will have to look into it and get back to you. +1 for presentation, documentation and instructions. If all works well for me then I will accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I saw a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11787090/279175) which gets to the root of your problem; the v4 pager doesn't support the android.app.Fragment, but rather a v4 version of it, which PreferenceFragment isn't derived from.

Comment: Yeah I found that a couple days after I posted this question. I was about to delete the question but it appears that your resolution might work.

Comment: This works great. Your thorough description saved me tons of trouble. Thanks

Comment: @PseudoNoise so it wont support lower devices ?

Comment: @DivyaRamakrishnan correct, you'd have to stick with the v4 support libs to support lower devices and not use the android.app.fragment.

Comment: `com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1` if you're on Android Studio.

Comment: Thank you so much, this just solved a couple of problems I had with the v4 library. Great explanation on how to make the world a little easier!

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29)

I think you need to specify a container view id for the fragment transaction. Try giving it the id of your ViewPager. Or, put the ViewPager inside another container, give that an id, and use that.